# Unable to access component from different module in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to access my component which is defined in separate module in angular app in my app.module. I have exported the component as well and imported the module in my app module as defined below:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [TabsComponent, SelectProviderComponent, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [TabsComponent, SelectProviderComponent, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent],
})
```

It still throwing me an error that component is not defined. Any leads?

Comment: Your question is not clear... Correct me if I am wrong, you have a component which is defined in a module, and you want use that component in some other module?

Comment: The above code seems fine. Assuming that the above is the other module, and you have imported this module in app.module.ts imports array. If it's still not working, try to stop the server and start again. Sometimes the auto-build doesn't read newly created/imported modules.

Comment: @Kenny Yes- I want to use my created component in other module.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer - Thanks to @Nayak in above comment. I restarted the server, build the app again and it worked like a charm.

Thanks!